# Scala reduction with non-primitive lists

Tags: scala, list, function

The following function calculates the Euclidean distance between two 2D points in Scala:

```
def euclideanDist(pt1: List[Double], pt2: List[Double]): Double =
  sqrt(pow(pt1(0)-pt2(0), 2)+pow(pt1(1)-pt2(1), 2))
```

I would like to design a perimeter function to accumulate the distances between each consecutive points in a list of points (or a ListBuffer).

For instance

```
val arr:ListBuffer[List[Double]] = ListBuffer(List(0, 0), List(0,1), List(1,1), List(1,0), List(0, 0))
perimeter(arr)
```

should give the output as 4.

This is what I tried:

```
def perimeter(arr: ListBuffer[List[Double]]): Double = 
  arr.reduceLeft(euclideanDist)
```

On execution, the compiler throws this error

```
Name: Unknown Error
Message: <console>:43: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (List[Double], List[Double]) => Double
 required: (Any, List[Double]) => Any
         arr.reduceLeft(euclideanDist)
                        ^
<console>:43: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: Double
         arr.reduceLeft(euclideanDist)
                       ^
StackTrace:
```

I could go imperative and do the whole thing with a for-loop, but would like to know if this can be solved simpler in the Scala way.

Comment: isn't `def perimeter(ListBuffer[List[Double]]: arr)` supposed to be `def perimeter(arr: ListBuffer[List[Double]])`?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: Yup. Made a mistake while refactoring in SO. Just made the edit. (The error is still the same though :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What with this:

```
val arr:List[List[Double]] = List(List(0, 0), List(0,1), List(1,1), List(1,0), List(0, 0))

arr.sliding(2).map{case List(a,b) => euclideanDist(a,b)}.sum
```

Comment: From https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html `def sliding(size: Int): Iterator[Seq[A]]
Groups elements in fixed size blocks by passing a "sliding window" over them (as opposed to partitioning them, as is done in grouped.) The "sliding window" step is set to one.`

Comment: `arr.sliding(2).toList`
`res1: List[List[List[Int]]] = List(List(List(0, 0), List(0, 1)), List(List(0, 1), List(1, 1)), List(List(1, 1), List(1, 0)), List(List(1, 0), List(0, 0)))`
sliding returns elements as 2 elements list. So you can unpack it by pattern matching `case List(a,b)` is a synthetic sugar for `map( l match { case List(a,b) => }`